# how to calculate total of the time field values in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services

I need to get a sum of the time values in my reporting services.

such as the sum of `23:26:26` and `26:26:56`

i tried by following:

```
 > Sum(Fields!item.Value)
```

but it won't work. Please help!

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

**try the `timespan` class :**

```
=TimeSpan(Sum(Fields!Item.Value))
```